# reading files asynchronously in parallel

Tags: node.js, fs

My node.js application requires several files. I understand that it's recommended to read files asynchronously, so, apparently I have to do something like this:

```
fs.readFile("file1", function(...) {
  fs.readFile("file2", function(...) {
    fs.readFile("file3", function(...) {
       [my application]
    }
  }
}
```

However, in this case, the files will be read sequentially.

Is there a way to read many files in parallel, and still make sure that the application starts after ALL of them have been loaded?

Comment: Are you opposed to flow-control libraries like [async.js](https://github.com/caolan/async/)? They can really help improve the readability of code like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty easy.

```
var files = [...], remaining = files.length;
var callback = function () {
    remaining--;
    if (!remaining) {
        go();
    }
};
files.forEach(function(file) {
    fs.readFile(file, callback);
});
```

Comment: It looks unnatural to put the application ('go') inside a callback. Is there a way to make sure that the application runs only after the files are loaded, but without putting the application in a callback? Something like "wait(remaining==0)"?

Comment: If you want to do that, you need to make sure that the `wait` function can resolve the `remaining` reference. For example: `function wait(propName, compare){var int=setInterval(function(){if(global[propName] == compare){clearInterval(int);go();}}, 10);}`. Then call it so: `wait('remaining', 0)`

Answer (score 2):

You can use a modern Promise-based API:

```js
import {promises as fs} from 'fs';

function readFiles(files) {
  return Promise.all(
    files.map(path => fs.readFile(path))
  );
}

readFiles(['file1', 'file2', 'file3'])
  .then(fileContents => {
    console.log('All the files are read', fileContents);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use module `async`

```js
const async = require('async')

async.each(
  ['dir1/file2.txt', 'dir2/file3.txt', 'dir/file5.txt'], 
  (file, callback) => {
    fs.readFile(file, (err, data) => {
      if (err) callback(Error(err))
      else {
        console.log(data)
        callback()
      }
    })
  },
  function(err) {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err)
    } else {
      console.log('All files have been read OK')
    }
})
```